# What are the ideal page margins to use in LaTex

Tags: margins

I am new and I wanted to see what was the ideal page margins to use?

***EDIT***: I mean if I to write an article or a small document.

I've been using the standard margins and they seem to be okay

Comment: I am afraid that your question is too broad to be answered. As a LaTeX user for years I can just tell you that the default margins for every documentclass can be considered to have the best possible fit to the documentclass, but also, while you are finalizing your document you may realize for example that each section starts from the bottom of a page, and thus, a small decrease on its margins (by respecting the general geometry -i.e. the fraction of left/right margin-) would improve the overall look of the document by moving all sections to start on the top of the pages and not on the bottom

Comment: for example, what do you use?

Comment: @john It highly depends on people's opinion, and opinion-based questions are not really welcome in this site. Personally I mostly use `margin=1in` or `margin=2cm`.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from however I think this is a good question for future users of LaTex in my humble opinion.

Comment: This isn’t really a good match for this site, because the answer is a matter of personal opinion about typography, unrelated to TeX specifically. However, you might want to look at the discussions of this topic in the `memoir` package, the Koma classes, and `classicthesis`, whose authors all had different opinions.

Comment: You could try this code to see the default margins for every documentclass `\documentclass{book}\usepackage{layout}\begin{document}\layout\end{document}` and then you could use `geometry` pcakage to change them to fit in your specific document needs (for me the less possible changes is the best)

Comment: Related discussion on the default margins here: [Why are default LaTeX margins so big?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/71172).

Comment: I think that this is a good question. I realise that it is opinion based but pointers could be given to professional's opinions on the subject. For instance Robert Bringhurst's *The Elements of Typographic Style,*  Hartley & Marks, or even my contribution via `texdoc memdesign`. (I would have given an expanded version of this as an answer if I had been allowed).

Comment: @PeterWilson Question reopened :)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is, basically, "What looks good to you". However there are some sources which talk about "What looks good to the majority". My favourite is Robert Bringhurst's *The Elements of Typographic Style* published by Hartley & Marks. For an immediate view of page layouts you could look at my *A Few Notes on Book Design* (`> texdoc memdesign`).

The basic idea is to have the text readable; typical recommendations are that in a single column document there should be about 60 to 70 characters per line and in two columns about 45 characters per line. Following deciding on the size of the typeblock, then the margins are constrained by the size of the paper. There are many ways in which you can change the four margins (upper, lower, inner, outer) to pleasing place the typeblock on the page.

The above publications, among others, give examples of many different kinds of layouts.

In my view the default LaTeX typeblock is a reasonable size but that it gets printed on paper (A4 or letterpaper) that is too large (i.e., the margins come out as too large).